# calculate means for combinations of 2 columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table

I'm hoping for help generating the means for combinations multiple columns of a df using dplyr, and -assuming one can - I can't get the syntax right.

```
df <- data.frame(trt1=c(replicate(6, "far"), replicate(6, "near")),
                 trt2=rep(c("A","A","A","B","B","B"), 2), 
                 count=sample(1:8, 12, replace=T))
```

I know how to get the means by one column:

```
df %>% group_by(trt1) %>% summarise(avg=mean(count))
```

But can't figure out the syntax for combinations of columns: far x A, far x B, near x A, near x B.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add trt2 to the group_by statement.

```
df %>% group_by(trt1,trt2) %>% summarise(avg=mean(count))

    trt1   trt2      avg
  <fctr> <fctr>    <dbl>
1    far      A 3.000000
2    far      B 1.333333
3   near      A 5.000000
4   near      B 4.666667
```

Comment: MO*#@@*KER! I was trying this df %>%group_by(trt1) %>% group_by(trt2)  %>% summarise(avg=mean(count))

Comment: Thanks very much - my headache is suddenly gone.

Answer (score 0):

A simple linear model also gives the answer in this case (just remind of removing the intercept to get the right contrasts) (I did some tuning to make give the dplyr *look*)

```
df %>% lm(count~trt1:trt2-1, .) %>% .$coef
#### trt1far:trt2A trt1near:trt2A  trt1far:trt2B trt1near:trt2B 
####      4.000000       4.333333       4.000000       4.666667
```

*(since there is no seed for the definition of your data.Frame, the result is different from the other answers)*